# cant convert a weight measurement saved as an object to an int/double/numeric value only

Tags: python

we're new programmers and our issue seems to be that
weight is an object such as 15'2 and we're trying to make it into a number such as 15.2, we cant seem to figure it out, some functions we've tried are

```
def value_to_int(df_value):
try:
    value = float(df_value[1:-1])
    suffix = df_value[-1:]
    if suffix == 'M':
        value = value * 1000000
    elif suffix == 'K':
        value = value * 1000
except ValueError:
    value = 0
return value
df['Value_float'] = df['Value'].apply(value_to_int)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-9a5ed573b054> in <module>()
 14     return value
 15 
---> 16 df['Value_float'] = df['Height'].apply(value_to_int)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3192             else:
   3193                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3194                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3195 
   3196         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-143-9a5ed573b054> in value_to_int(df_value)
  3 def value_to_int(df_value):
  4     try:
----> 5         value = float(df_value[1:-1])
  6         suffix = df_value[-1:]
  7 

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Hello, what's your type(input) and what's your expected type(output) ?

Comment: Is your input something like a string 15'2 and you want to convert it to float?

Comment: you are doing it all wrong starting from the way you have asked the question to the way you operate on your dataframe. show us your input and explain what you want to achieve (desired output) and we will guide you through. why do not you slice your data and separate it e.g. if you get a string M5'2 when strip M into separate column and 5'2 into separate colum and do apply function to the whole column to replace '2 with . and make float out of int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'val':["M15'2","K13'3", "17'4"]})
df['sex'] = df['val'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+", x)))

# split string on sex
def split_str(row):
    if row['sex']:
        return row['val'].split(row['sex']).pop()
    else:
        return row['val']

df['weight'] = df.apply(lambda row: split_str(row), axis=1)
df['weight'] = df['weight'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("'", "."))
df['weight'] = df['weight'].astype(float)

# modify weight on sex
def multiply_weight(row):
    if row['sex'] == 'M':
        row['weight'] = row['weight'] * 1000000
    elif row['sex'] == 'K':
        row['weight'] = row['weight'] * 1000
    else:
        row['weight'] = 0
    return row

# return final df
df = df.apply(lambda row: multiply_weight(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform "12'5" to float, you first need to replace the ' for a . so your code will look like:

```
def value_to_int(df_value):
    try:
        value = float(df_value[1:-1].replace("'", "."))
        suffix = df_value[-1:]
        if suffix == 'M':
            value = value * 1000000
        elif suffix == 'K':
            value = value * 1000
    except ValueError:
        value = 0
    return value
df['Value_float'] = df['Value'].apply(value_to_int)
```

Best!